# Keeping connection for Golang net/rpc

Tags: go, rpc

As I understand, reading net/rpc package documentation here
https://pkg.go.dev/net/rpc@go1.17.5 that every time a client makes an rpc call to the server, a new connection established. How can achieve that each new client opens a new connection, keeps it alive and invokes RPC methods using only TPC, i.e. not using HTTP?

Comment: Why do you think that each call invokes a new connection?

Comment: @JimB after reading documentation. I haven't seen anything about keeping connections etc.

Comment: _"A client wishing to use the service establishes a connection and then invokes `NewClient` on the connection"_, a client is based on a single connection

Comment: yes, and what happens after a remote call? I guess, connection auto-closed. I need to have a possibility to keep a list of all open connections on the server

Comment: The connection is retained by the [client](https://pkg.go.dev/net/rpc#Client) until the application explicitly [closes the client](https://pkg.go.dev/net/rpc#Client.Close).   The application must close the client to prevent leaks.  There's no need to keep a list of all open clients to a server — just reuse a single client to the server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you make a new client with any of the standard library methods:

```golang
client, err := rpc.DialHTTP("tcp", serverAddress + ":1234")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("dialing:", err)
}
```

Underneath the hood it will [call `net.Dial`](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.17.5:src/net/rpc/client.go;l=248;bpv=1;bpt=1), resulting in a single connection that is associated with the `rpc.Client`:

```golang
conn, err := net.Dial(network, address)
```

You can see NewClient taking a single connection when it's instantiated here: https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.17.5:src/net/rpc/client.go;l=193-197;drc=refs%2Ftags%2Fgo1.17.5;bpv=1;bpt=1

Any calls to `Client.Call` on that client will write and read to that underlying connection without spawning a new connection.

So as long as you instantiate your client one time and then make all of your rpc calls to that same client you'll always use a single connection. If that connection ever is severed the client will not longer be usable.

`rpc.Client` is also threadsafe, so you can safely create it and use it all over the place without having to make new connections .

---

Answering your comment. If you wanted to run an rpc server and keep track of connections you could do this:

```golang
l, e := net.Listen("tcp", ":1234")
if e != nil {
    log.Fatal("listen error:", e)
}
server := rpc.NewServer()
for {
    conn, err := l.Accept()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err) // replace with log message?
    }
    // Do something with `conn`
    go func() {
        server.ServeConn(conn)
        // The server has stopped serving this connection, you can remove it.
    }()
}
```

And then do something with each connection as it came in, and remove it when it's done processing.

Comment: Thanks, what will be a server code to keep a list of all connections and access them (by server) if needed?


I saw this code, does it mean that rpc.ServeConn call keeps this connection active inside? ..and if I want to have access to all connections, I need to save a link to conn somewhere before that call?

    for {
        conn, err := listener.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            continue
        }
        rpc.ServeConn(conn)
    }
here https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmfYeDhGH9bZzihBUDEQbCbTc5k5FZKURMUoUvfmc27BwL/rpc/go_rpc.html

Comment: edit: oh I see what you're saying, let me add how to do that to the answer

Comment: answered above ^